# Removing 2nd span within a div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to remove a span tag with in a div. Here is what I have:

```
<div id="row-title-7">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
</div>
```

I need to remove this one:

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
```

I have tried several things and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Could you show what you  have tried? You have to select the right element and use `remove()`. What are you having problems with?

Comment: You need to remove the exactly 2nd one or the '...-1-s' one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will the span you remove always have a different class than the ones you want to keep? If so just do:

```
$('#row-title-7').children('.ui-icon-triangle-1-s').remove();
```

If the class will differ but it will always be the 2nd span, you coule use:

```
$('#row-title-7:nth-child(2)').remove();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#row-title-7').children().last().remove();
```

or

```
 $('#row-title-7').children('.ui-icon-triangle-1-s').remove();
```

or

```
$('#row-title-7').children('span .ui-icon-triangle-1-s').remove();
```

if u have more element mix with span last issuitable

Comment: That works, but $('#row-title-7 span:eq(1)').remove(); would remove exactly the second one (in case there are more than two span)

Comment: Also $("span[class$='-s']") = remove where class endsWith -s

Answer (score 1):

You should do this:

```
 $("#row-title-7").find("span.ui-icon-triangle-1s").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#row-title-7 span').eq(1).remove();
```

## *[playground](http://jsbin.com/#javascript,html,live)*

**http://api.jquery.com/eq/**

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, not sure what action or event you want to have this 'removal' occur,

```
<script>
$("ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s").click(function () {
$("ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s").toggle();
});
</script>
```

You will need the latest jQuery installed.

Comment: I can't see any functions in that code that are only available in the latest version of jQuery.